# Passive FTP Timeout while using WinINet

Tags: windows, ftp, wininet, passive-mode

I'm trying to ftp a file using passive ftp but I get a timeout (12002) when the `put` command is called.

I'm able to use passive ftp with other ftp sites but not this new one.

I've tried this using three different ways on the same server:

> - FileZilla Client in passive mode - this works
> - WinINet libarary in passive mode - I get a timeout when calling PutFile
> - IE 6 in passive mode - I get a timeout when the directory listing is attempted

This is on a Windows 2000 server.

I assume my firewall is set up correctly since FileZilla worked.

Can anyone help me figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

In Passive mode, the FTP server opens a port on its end and tells the FTP client the IP/Port it needs to connect to.  On the client end, it creates a new socket, binds it to a local IP/Port (usually a random IP/Port unless configured otherwise), and connects to the server's specified IP/Port.  Without actually seeing a trace log from a network packet sniffer, like Wireshark, then I would guess that either a firewall/router on the client end is blocking the outbound connection, or a firewall/router on the server end is blocking the inbound connection.  The fact that FileZilla is getting through OK probably means that the IP/Port pairs on both ends of the connection happen to match all the firewall/router rules for accepting connections on both ends, whereas something in the WinInet/IE IP/Port pairs is getting rejected instead. That is a little unusual since Passive mode tends to be more firewall/router friendly than Active mode, though. Have you tried using Windows' command-line ftp.exe utility to see if it works or not?  BTW, IE uses WinInet for all of its connections.

Comment: Windows command-line ftp gives me this error:  425 Unable to build data connection: Connection refused

I'm pretty sure it's because passive ftp isn't supported by ftp.exe.

I'll see if I can figure out which ports are being used by the two different programs.

Thank you